# How do you draw a method from a class that extends Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I'm in the process of making a memory game with java. I have a class that extends JButton that is used to draw the cards and I have a main runner class. Here is my Card class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Card extends JButton {
    private String cardValue;
    private boolean matched = false;
    private int width = 70;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Card(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));
    }

    public void drawFaceDown() {
        setBackground(new Color(214, 247, 202));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
    };

}
```

and here is my Runner class

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> tiles = new ArrayList<Card>();


        int NUM_COLS = 5;
        int NUM_ROWS = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
                tiles.add(new Card(i * 78 + 10, j * 78 + 40));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
            tiles.get(i).drawFaceDown();
        }






    }
}
```

In the for loop I try to use the drawFaceDown() however nothing is drawn on the graphics panel. Can someone help me with what's going on.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: I tried looking for some tutorials to add JButtons to a graphics panel and this is what I found. import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class BasicSwing extends JFrame{
 
 JPanel p=new JPanel();
 JButton b=new JButton("Hello"); 
 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  new BasicSwing();
 }
 
 public BasicSwing(){
  super("Basic Swing App");
  
  setSize(400,300);
  setResizable(true);
  
  p.add(b);
  p.add(t);
  p.add(ta);
  p.add(l);
  p.add(cb);
  add(p);
  
  setVisible(true);
 }
}

Comment: However, I have to add the buttons in the constructor. In my example I'm trying to do it in a for loop and p.add() wouldn't work. So how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the Cards to a `JFrame`. Going by your code, `GridLayout` will be the best for you. Change your `Runner` class like so. I have scaled the size of buttons a bit.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> tiles = new ArrayList<Card>();

        JFrame frame =  new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        int NUM_COLS = 5;
        int NUM_ROWS = 4;

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS));

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
                tiles.add(new Card(i * 8 + 10, j * 8 + 40));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
            frame.add(tiles.get(i));
            tiles.get(i).drawFaceDown();
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Also, read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Comment: the GUI stuff should all be done on the EventDispatch thread, not the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the button to Panel in order to show it somewhere. Something like:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(tiles.get(i).drawFaceDown());
```